# How do I download the NLTK's entire free resources?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

On my Mac, installing bare-bones NLTK and typing`nltk.download()` worked fine. It gave a popup window and was smooth sailing from there.

Now I am having trouble with a remove server (a Linux VPS with shell). I added nltk to Python 2 and Python 3, and ran `nltk.download()` from the server. The latter gave me non-functioning ASCII art of a checkbox:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20)  [GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.

>>> import nltk

>>> nltk.download() NLTK Downloader

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q)           
Quit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Downloader> h



Commands:   d) Download a package or collection     u) Update out of
date packages   l) List packages & collections          h) Help   c)

View & Modify Configuration          q) Quit



---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Downloader> s Command 's' unrecognized

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) Quit

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Downloader> a Command 'a' unrecognized



---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    d) Download   l) List    u) Update   c) Config   h) Help   q) 
Quit

---------------------------------------------------------------------
------ Downloader> d


Download which package (l=list; x=cancel)?   Identifier> l Packages:  
[ ] abc................. Australian Broadcasting Commission 2006   [ ]
alpino.............. Alpino Dutch Treebank   [ ]
averaged_perceptron_tagger Averaged Perceptron Tagger   [ ]
basque_grammars..... Grammars for Basque   [ ] biocreative_ppi.....
BioCreAtIvE (Critical Assessment of Information
                           Extraction Systems in Biology)   [ ] 
bllip_wsj_no_aux.... BLLIP Parser: WSJ Model   [ ]
book_grammars....... Grammars from NLTK Book   [ ]
brown_tei........... Brown Corpus (TEI XML Version)   [ ]
cess_cat............ CESS-CAT Treebank   [ ] cess_esp............
CESS-ESP Treebank   [ ] chat80.............. Chat-80 Data Files   [ ]
city_database....... City Database   [ ] cmudict............ The
Carnegie Mellon Pronouncing Dictionary (0.6)   [ ]
comparative_sentences Comparative Sentence Dataset   [ ]
comtrans............ ComTrans Corpus Sample   [ ] conll2000...........
CONLL 2000 Chunking Corpus   [ ] conll2002........... CONLL 2002 Named
Entity Recognition Corpus   [ ] conll2007........... Dependency
Treebanks from CoNLL 2007 (Catalan
                           and Basque Subset)
```

I know I don't need the other languages; I know a few of them, but at partial proficiency.

I would like to be able use the NLTK demonstration as discussed in https://pythonprogramming.net/wordnet-nltk-tutorial/ . It uses brown and probably other packages; but part of my major goal is to be able to calculate distance between words.

Comment: If you've got them locally, wouldn't it be easier to upload them from your machine to the server, rather than try to run the downloader headless? Also, I did my best with the formatting, but it's probably better if you copy and paste from your terminal then use the `{}` button or Ctrl-K to apply code block formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a chance to try this?

```
python -m nltk.downloader all
```

This is straight [from the documentation](http://www.nltk.org/data.html)